# Shortening function definitions using multine patterns in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching

Is it better to do:

```
charToAction 'q' = Just $ WalkRight False
charToAction 'd' = Just $ WalkRight True
charToAction 'z' = Just Jump
charToAction _ = Nothing
```

or

```
charToAction x = case x of
    'q' -> Just $ WalkRight False
    'd' -> Just $ WalkRight True
    'z' -> Just Jump
    _ -> Nothing
```

?

Comment: Which one do you like better? There's no performance difference in either of these solutions. Just go with the one you personally like better in terms of syntax.

Comment: if, case, guards, pattern-matching, I'm torn apart by these!

Comment: `if` and guards aren't good options for this, but the two you're asking about are indeed equivalent – as a matter of fact, GHC will pack different patterns for a function in a `case` statement in the first compilation step anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's absolutely no functional difference whatsoever. It's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: There is a alight difference when you have multiple arguments with regards to the willingness to back up and retry, but you can always desugar to the case statements, since that is what happens in ghc core. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance difference *because* the first definition desugars to the second. You were right to prefer a case + pattern matching solution to one with guards and an equality test, some excellent general remarks are here: http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/ (His examples are in ML but  translate immediately to Haskell).

Note that you are misusing `otherwise` in the second definition; you should just write `_ -> Nothing` It isn't the `otherwise` of guards that you are using, you could as well have written `fmap -> Nothing` and the same would have happened.

Comment: Thanks for the article! It's true booleans are very low-level and thus should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, there is no difference in the generated code as the former approach desugars to the latter approach, however I can point out some other considerations that may help you choose one or the other to use:

1. The former approach looks prettier in some circumstances (although I personally think that once you have lots of cases it is distracting)
2. The former approach makes it slightly more difficult to refactor the name.  Using the case statement the name of the function only appears once.
3. Case statements can be used anywhere in your code and can be used anonymously.  The former approach requires using a `let` or `where` block to define pattern-matching functions within a function.

However, there are no cases where you can't translate one into the other.  It's entirely a matter of coding style.